# tastypie - disable nested objects creation

Tags: python, django, tastypie

When i'm creating a new resource with a foreign relation, specified as, i.e., `{"pk": 20}`, i get a new unwanted FK-item created.

I have `Order` model class with a relations to the `Language` model, so when creating an Order instance, i may have to specify the order's languages. Language list should be constant, and the users must not have an ability to modify existant or to create the new languages.

`Order` resource:

```
class OrderResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', null=True, full=True)
    src_lang = fields.ForeignKey(LanguageResource, 'src_lang', null=True, full=True)
    dst_lang = fields.ForeignKey(LanguageResource, 'dst_lang', null=True, full=True)

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        return super(OrderResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, user=request.user)

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'orders'
        queryset = Order.objects.all()
        serializer = Serializer(['json'])

        authentication = MultiAuthentication(SessionAuthentication(), ApiKeyAuthentication())
        authorization = ResourceAuthorization()
```

And here is a `Language` resource:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class LanguageResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'languages'
        queryset = Language.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        authorization = ReadOnlyAuthorization()
        serializer = Serializer(['json'])
```

I'm trying to create a new `Order` with jQuery:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
    "comment": "Something random",
    "src_lang": {"pk": "20"},
    "dst_lang": "/api/v2/languages/72/"
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/v2/orders/',
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Instead of setting the `pk:20` to `src_lang_id` field, it creates a new `Language` with empty fields for `src_lang` and sets a correct value for `dst_lang`. But empty fields are restricted with the `Language` model definition. How it saves it?

Also it's enough strange because i've straightly specified readonly access for language model, and only `get` method for accessing the supported language list.

If i declare language fields of `OrderResource` class as, i.e.: `src_lang = fields.ForeignKey(LanguageResource, 'src_lang', null=True, full=True, readonly=True)`, it creates nothing, but also does not set any values for the foreign keys.

So, i just need to specify an existant language, i don't need to create it.

## UPDATE

`ResourceAuthorization`:

```
class ResourceAuthorization(Authorization):
    def is_authorized(self, request, object=None):
        user = getattr(request, 'user', None)
        if not user:
            return False

        return user.is_authenticated()

    def apply_limits(self, request, object_list):
        if request and hasattr(request, 'user'):
            if request.user.is_superuser:
                return object_list

            return object_list.filter(user=request.user)

        return object_list.none()
```

## UPDATE 2

I found nothing more clever making fields read only and overriding `obj_create` method:

```
class OrderResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', null=True, full=True)
    src_lang = fields.ForeignKey(LanguageResource, 'src_lang', null=True, full=True, blank=True, readonly=True)
    dst_lang = fields.ForeignKey(LanguageResource, 'dst_lang', null=True, full=True, blank=True, readonly=True)

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        src_lang_id, dst_lang_id = bundle.data.get('src_lang', None), bundle.data.get('dst_lang', None)

        if not all([src_lang_id, dst_lang_id]):
            raise BadRequest('You should specify both source and destination language codes')

        src_lang, dst_lang = Language.objects.guess(src_lang_id), Language.objects.guess(dst_lang_id)
        if not all([src_lang, dst_lang]):
            raise BadRequest('You should specify both source and destination language codes')

        return super(OrderResource, self).obj_create(
            bundle, request, user=request.user, src_lang=src_lang, dst_lang=dst_lang
        )

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'orders'
        queryset = Order.objects.all()
        serializer = Serializer(['json'])

        authentication = MultiAuthentication(SessionAuthentication(), ApiKeyAuthentication())
        authorization = ResourceAuthorization()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428613/302243) answer to your question, `src_lang` should correspond to a *resource*, not to some other value.  I suspect that when the POST occurs and it doesn't find a resource `pk=20`, it creates a new `Language` object and calls `save` without Django model validation, allowing a blank field to exist in the created `Language`.

One way of forcing a read-only type resource is to create a resource which doesn't allow `obj_create`.

```
class ReadOnlyLanguageResource(ModelResource):
    # All the meta stuff here.
    def obj_create(self):
        # This should probably raise some kind of http error exception relating
        # to permission denied rather than Exception.
        raise Exception("Permission denied, cannot create new language resource")
```

This resource is then referenced from your `Order` resource, overriding just the `src_lang` field to point to your read only resource.

```
class OrderResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', null=True, full=True)
    src_lang = fields.ForeignKey(ReadOnlyLanguageResource, 'src_lang')
    dst_lang = fields.ForeignKey(ReadOnlyLanguageResource, 'dst_lang')
```

Any request that references an existing resource will complete as per normal (but you'll need to reference the resource correctly, not using `pk=20`).  Any request the references an unknown language will fail as a new `Language` object cannot be created.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the `src_lang` in the format `/api/v2/languages/72/` corresponding the `pk=20`.

Secondly what exactly is `ResourceAuthorization`? The [documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html) lists `ReadOnlyAuthorization` which might be useful to you.

Also the authorization applies the resource, not the underlying model. When creating a new object for `fk`, it does not use the REST Api but `django.db.models` and its permissions. So the authorizations might not apply via the foreign key constraint.

Comment: I see the format it should be specified, i don't understand why it creates a new `Language` instance. If i wil use `/api/v2/languages/20/` for src_lang, it works fine. `ResourceAuthorization` is [a per user authorization](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#creating-per-user-resources)

Comment: I see the ResourceAuthorization now, but I'm not sure of its correctness.